# Rails: Using same custom validation method for multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, custom-validators

I have this method in 3 models, so I'd like to extract it and DRY things up. I'm also having problem with the default value of the attr. When the field is empty it will be evaluated as empty string `""` instead of `nil`, so I have to write the conditional in the method to avoid adding the "http" to empty string.

Where should I put the method and how can I include it in the models?

Should I optimize the method? If so, where and how can I set the default attr value to `nil` (rails/db/both)?

```
before_validation :format_website

def format_website
  if website == ""
    self.website = nil
  elsif website.present? && !self.website[/^https?/]
    self.website = "http://#{self.website}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your method in the *app/models/concerns* folder, for example, as `Validatable` module (i.e. *validatable.rb*):

```
module Concerns::Validatable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def format_website
    if website.blank?
      self.website = nil
    elsif !self.website[/^https?/]
      self.website = "http://#{self.website}"
    end
  end

end
```

And then include it in each models as

```
include Concerns::Validatable
```

Comment: potashin, and then simply call from every model with `before_validation :format_website` ?

Comment: @SzilardMagyar: yes

Comment: potashin, let me ask one more question. Is the method good enough this way or I should do something with this `nil` vs `""` issue?

Comment: potashin, this should be autoloaded by default in rails 4.2.6, right? For some reason I get `load_missing_constant': Unable to autoload constant Concerns::Validatable, expected /Users/Silo/Desktop/ruby_on_rails/faskyn/app/models/concerns/validatable.rb to define it (LoadError)`

Comment: Sry it was my bad, forgot about the namspacing! Thanks for the answer!